# Swift: How to draw UIs in Playground?

Tags: xcode, swift

How to draw UIs (Rectangle, Buttons, Views, etc) and view the results in real-time, as shown here: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/swift/images/swift-screenshot.jpg ? All I can see is the Console Output, but I can't find the option to show the visual display (Balloons) and the chart.

Comment: Maybe check this thread, for a simple sample ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045339/how-to-use-swift-playground-to-display-nsview-with-some-drawing/24070530#24070530

Comment: On Xcode 8 and Swift 3, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919276/how-to-get-a-canvas-in-a-swift-playground

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Charts appear in the Assistant editor when you have something like a `for` loop, or for anything where you press the quick look or circle/plus buttons when mousing over the results area. See [Viewing Results of an Executed Statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ViewingResults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015166-CH37-SW1) in [Playground Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015166).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to that link. Very useful. The circle wasn't obvious.

Comment: The link isn't working. Here's the updated link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/ExploringandEvaluatingSwiftCodeinaPlayground.htm

Comment: It looks like Apple has hosed their docs again. In Safari, I get ∞ loading at those links now.