# How to get a Canvas in a Swift Playground

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I would like to get a canvas that I can use to draw on. The target would be an iOS based Swift playground. I searched the documentation and I could not found an object named Canvas, but if there is something similar to it then it would be good for me as well.

Comment: You can use a `UIView` as a drawing canvas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something similar to this, note you don't have to use Sprite Kit classes.

```
import UIKit 
import PlaygroundSupport 
import SpriteKit 


//    Playground Container Setup 
// 
// 
let containerWidth: CGFloat = 667.0 
let containerHeight: CGFloat = 375.0 
let containerCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: (containerWidth/2), y: (containerHeight/2)) 


let containerView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight)) 


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView 


let containterScene: SKScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight)) 
containerView.presentScene(containterScene)
```

**UPDATED**

I've created a wrapper class to make this easier for everyone. Download the Playground here on **[github](https://github.com/xnukernel/PlaygroundCanvas)**

Comment: I pasted the code but the PlaygroundSupport import generates an error message in Xcode 7 about missing module.

Comment: The `Playground Support` module is only available in Xcode 8 with Swift 3.0.

Comment: In Xcode 7 use the module `XCPlayground` and instead of `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView` use the following: `XCPShowView(identifier: String, view: UIView)`